# destroy session on page closing asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm working on web application :

you got a page for search at user and when you choose the user you want its open a new page with the id of the user

```
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("var newWindow = window.open('UpdateUser.aspx?id="+Encryption.Encypt_URL(btn.CommandArgument)+"'); newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);");
        Response.Write("</script>");
```

in update user there is two state : 
take the id from the querystring if session not registered or take it from the session

```
if (Session["id"] == null)
            {id = Encryption.Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"]);
             Session["id"] = Encryption.Encrypt(id+"");
            }
else
            {
                id = int.Parse(Encryption.Decrypt(Session["id"].ToString()));}
```

It's working fine ... but the problem is:
when I want to choose another user... it choose the first one 
so I need to clear the session but don't know where to did it ?

Comment: `Session["id"] = null;` - However, each user should have their own unique ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : 
every choose just clear the session

```
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Session["id"] = null;
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("var newWindow = window.open('UpdateUser.aspx?id="+Encryption.Encypt_URL(btn.CommandArgument)+"'); newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);");
        Response.Write("</script>");
```